# JQuery hover menu that works like a regular menu if the browser has javascript disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make this code not have the hover point links' pictures not come up if the browser has Javascript disable? And then have the links work like a regular hover point when Javascript is disable?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.2.2.pack.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
// set opacity to nill on page load
$("ul#bnavmenu span").css("opacity", "0");
// on mouse over
$("ul#bnavmenu span").hover(function () {
// animate opacity to full
$(this).stop().animate({
opacity: 1
}, 'slow');
},
// on mouse out
function () {
// animate opacity to nill
$(this).stop().animate({
opacity: 0
}, 'slow');
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your full menu you can set css hover rules

```
ul#bnavmenu span {
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
-moz-opacity:0;
}

ul#bnavmenu span:hover {
opacity:1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
-moz-opacity:1;
}
```

and if you really want to go for the gold you could use css3 animations http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

You just said "If the browser has JavaScript disabled", how will it read your code?

You need to use a no script tags and put your custom styling & tags between for people with javascript turnerd off.

```
<noscript>
tags and css
</noscript>
```